# I moved magento folders from ftp.When I open store on my wamp localhost, it gives the error mentioned below

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-community

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'finfid.log_visitor_info' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `log_visitor_info`

Trace:

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `log_v...', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `log_v...', Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(171): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DESCRIBE `log_v...')
#6 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1596): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('log_visitor_inf...', NULL)
#7 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(212): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('log_visitor_inf...')
#8 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Resource\Visitor.php(172): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->_prepareDataForTable(Object(Varien_Object), 'log_visitor_inf...')
#9 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Resource\Visitor.php(108): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(463): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#11 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#12 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Log\Model\Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#14 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#15 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#16 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#17 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#18 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#19 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 C:\wamp\www\local\magento\index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the explanation in the error description `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'finfid.log_visitor_info' doesn't exist`
You must use the database you used before. Here is missing a table `log_visitor_info`.

---

In case there is the only one missing here you can find the SQL to create it :
`CREATE TABLE 'log_visitor_info' (
  'visitor_id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
  'http_referer' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Referrer',
  'http_user_agent' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP User-Agent',
  'http_accept_charset' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Charset',
  'http_accept_language' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Language',
  'server_addr' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Server Address',
  'remote_addr' bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Remote Address'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitor Info Table';
ALTER TABLE 'log_visitor_info' ADD PRIMARY KEY ('visitor_id');`

---

For people who have the same error if query does not work is probably because of the quotes `'` that must be `. Here you can find the correct query to launch with correct quotes http://pastebin.com/jYCS2aGZ

Comment: Thank you for the solution.I ran above query on the database it says syntax error on line 1.-'visitor_id' bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' CO' at line 1.

Comment: Please try this query : http://pastebin.com/jYCS2aGZ I replace the quotes. The query is a direct extract from PhpMyAdmin so it is the correct one. Which MySQL version are you runing ?

Comment: Thank you.It fixed the current error.Please go through the link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96994/i-encountered-an-error-while-trying-to-move-magento-website-from-ftp-to-localhost.