# I encountered an error while trying to move MAgento website from FTP to localhost on WAMP

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.1.0, wamp

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXX.tag_summary' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `tag_summary`.`popularity`, `tag`.* FROM `tag_summary`
 INNER JOIN `tag` ON tag.tag_id = tag_summary.tag_id AND tag.status = 1 WHERE (tag_summary.store_id = '1') AND (tag_summary.products > 0) ORDER BY `popularity` DESC LIMIT 20

Comment: Please ask for trace if required.

Comment: Ensure your database tables don't have prefixes, could be the cause. Please double check that the tag_summary table exists in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the SQL to create the missing table : http://pastebin.com/JipuLqRt (take care if you have table prefix)

---

Like my response here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96630/33619 one solution you have to fix this kind of error is to install a clean Magento instance and use PhpMyAdmin (or other tool) to see table structure. With that you can find the SQL query to create the table.
For example I am using Sequel Pro and there is a tab for this :
[image]

Comment: It says #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Can you try this solution to have more information please : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535110/3531064